# 401 error while fetching data from Microsoft Graph API getEmailByUserActivity in react Application using Azure Active Directory

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, react-typescript

In my React Application I am trying to fetch a protected Graph API
but I am getting 401 authorization error. My graph API is [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period=%27D7%27)) or
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period=%27D7%27)?$format=application/json)

error is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTbxA.png)

permissions which have added in Azure Active Directory is
[enter image description here][2]

In my React Application setup is as such
[enter image description here][3]

Access token
[enter image description here][4]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTbxA.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ @Reyno's comment is correct.  Please follow the link they've provided and read the top answer about why images of code are almost guaranteed to get you no help from SO contributors.  You should edit your post and copy / paste the code in the images into the code-block feature you will find in your post